# Registration Form To Populate Excel Sheet

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel

I'm trying to add a web registration form for people to sign up for a lunch and learn. The idea would be once a user presses submit, his/her info would automatically post to the Excel sheet and the next person's would appear directly below the previous person.

I don't have access to the server side of things and can only manage to create/edit within the Sharepoint site.

Answer (score 1):

If you ask me there is no way to directly add the information from a input dialog to an excelsheet without using code.

However I would suggest setting up a Custom List with the fields you want to have. And let the users add information to the list.

[image]

Then you can export to excel.

[image]

And you get something like this:

[image]